# Create an Image with dynamic text on it using GD library

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I am creating a text watermark using GD Library. The problem is that when I give them a short text, it generates a normal image but when the text is larger the image becomes smaller. Please tell me how can I create image according to text so it fits nicely. This is the code I used so far:

```
 if(isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text']) ){

         $text = $_GET['text'];
         $font     = './NOTTB___.TTF';
         $fontsize = 20;
         $bbox   = imageftbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $text);
         $width = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
         $height = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7];


         $my_img = imagecreate( $width, $height );
         $background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0xff,0xff,0xff );
         $text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0x00,0x00,0x00 );
         imagecolortransparent($my_img, $background);

         //imagettftext($my_img, $fontsize, 0, 30, 25, $text_colour, $font, $text);
         imagefttext($my_img,$fontsize,0,-$bbox[6], -$bbox[7],$text_colour,$font,$text);

         header( "Content-type: image/png" );
         imagepng( $my_img );
         imagecolordeallocate( $text_colour );
         imagecolordeallocate( $background );
         imagedestroy( $my_img );

 }
```

Comment: I think your browser is just scaling the image down to fit it in your window, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Can you link to a couple example images showing both cases?

Comment: sammitch how can i share example with you so that you get some idea about my problem

Comment: yes you are right cmorrissey .now i removed width tag from that image and it work fine. thanks